# Sequence of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Assume $R$ is a ring with an element $r$. Assume $R/rR$ is flat as $R$-module. I would like to show that there is an exact sequence 
$r^2R \rightarrow rR \rightarrow rR \otimes_R (R/rR)\rightarrow 0$. There is obviously an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow rR \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/rR \rightarrow 0$ considering which I showed that $rR \otimes_R (R/rR) = 0$ but I am stuck on this following step. Can anyone give directions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please review [the advice here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) about question quality, and make revisions accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Tried to add some context. Let me know if you think it improved the question.

Comment: Is the ring $R$ commutative?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot. Commutative with unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Tensoring (on the left) with $rR$ yields a sequence
$$0\longrightarrow rR\otimes_R rR\longrightarrow rR\otimes_R R\longrightarrow rR\otimes_R R/rR\longrightarrow 0,$$which is exact because $R/rR$ is a flat $R$-module. Remember that $\; rR\otimes_R R\simeq rR$. With this identification, what is the image of $ rR\otimes_R rR$ in $rR\mkern1mu$?

Comment: rR, because it's the ker of the following arrow?

Comment: Yes, and mainly to obtain $r^2$.

Comment: Bear with me, how does it let one obtain $r^2$? Thanks for your reply by the way.

Comment: You have to identify $rR\otimes_R rR$ with its image in $rR$.

Comment: Which is the whole rR, but is $rR \otimes_R rR$ isomorphic to $r^2R$?

Comment: The image of the tensor product  in $rR$ is $r^2R$.

Comment: Ok I think I see it, thank you. Incidentally, can you tell why this exact sequence would imply that there is a $b \in A$ such that $r = r^2b$?

Comment: A priori, I don't see. Probably one is expected to show the image of $r\otimes 1$ in $rR\otimes_R R/rR$ is $0$. B.t.w., this last module is not $0$ in general, contrary to what you wrote: it's isomorphic to $rR/r^2R$.

Comment: Oh this is unsettling as it would imply an error in the exercise. That module $rR \otimes_R (R/rR)$ is certainly meant to be 0.

Comment: I only said ‘in general’. Maybe the fact that $R/rR$ is $R$-flat ensures the tensor product is $0$, but I don't see why.

Comment: One doubt on this. I would have thought that exactness is preserved only under tensoring with something flat. $rR$ is not flat though, is it?

Comment: No, it's not (unless if $R$ is an integral domain). The property which is used here is that a short exact sequence $0\to M\to N\to P\to 0$ with $P$ flat is ‘universally exact’, i.e. it remains exact after tensoring by any module. Such sequences are also called  `pure` exact sequences, if you've heard this terminology. Split exact sequences are pure too.

Comment: No I studied from book that is way too dry and without examples. Do you have any good suggestions of literature for this stuff? Sorry I know it's off topic.

Comment: I learnt the subject from Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. I *Flat  Modules*.  It's not so easy for beginners, but many exercises (not all easy). Other than that, I like Atiyah-Macdonald's *Commutative Algebra*, but it's far from being as complete on this particular subject.